# Cypress-cucumber - How to store steps in same directory as features

Tags: cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

Im trying to figure out how I can stop my step files in the same directory as my feature file. I have used the basic setup tutorial from cypress-cucumber page.

My issue is this.

I have a feature file in

integration/feautres/**test.feature**

to get the test to run I have to put my step file inside integration/feautres/**test**/test.js

What I want to do is store my step file, next to the feature like
integration/feautres/test.js

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not really possible. With cypress-cucumber-preprocessor, you have two options for storing your step definitions:

1. In your config, set `nonGlobalStepDefinitions` to `true`, which will look for feature-specific steps in the setup you have now (i.e. `/featureName/featureName.js`). With this option, all global steps will be stored in `cypress/integration/common`.
2. In your config, set `nonGlobalStepDefinitions` to `false`, which will keep your steps global, and they'll be in `cypress/support/step_definitions`.

I suppose it *could* be possible to go with option 1, then store your step definitions and feature files in the `cypress/integration/common` directory. However, if that works, this will cause you headaches as your tests and step definitions scale (think about having hundreds or thousands of globally accessible step definitions and accidentally creating duplicates...it gets messy quick).

Personally, I would highly advise against this.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I agree I wouldn't want a bunch of common steps. Hopefully in the future this feature will be added. Appreciate the in depth answer! Thank you

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad I could be of assistance. If you feel this this sufficiently answers your question, please consider marking it as the accepted answer.